# How to activate Xbox controller vibrations in Unity?

Tags: unity, input

Is there any way to toggle the XBOX controller vibrations in Unity ? I came across [Handheld.Vibrate()](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/350193/handheldvibrate-duration.html) but it seems like it's not meant for controllers.

Comment: In 2019.3.x you can done it using InputSystem : [a link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@0.9/manual/Gamepad.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right: The Handheld class just covers handheld devices but not controllers.

There is a library called XInput which should cover your needs. You'll find it on GitHub: https://github.com/speps/XInputDotNet. It is compatible with Unity 4 and 5.

Specifically for the XBox Controller and how to let it vibrate, this might help you: http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/375451/view.html